# Angular 8 - image not served via require() if parameter is a property

Tags: angular

In my Angular 8 webapp I am trying to load an image via function:  **require()**.
In my template I use:

```
<img [src]="logo" />
```

If in the component TS code I enter:

```
logo = require('./myImage.gif');
```

the above hard-typed path loads the image just fine.

However, I want to use a dynamic approach and pass the image path using a property (variable) e.g:

```
const imagePath = './myImage.gif';
logo = require(imagePath);
```

In this case the image is not loaded and browser debugger complains:

```
 Error: Cannot find module './myImage.gif' at webpackEmptyContext
```

What is the problem with passing a property to the function require()?
How can this be resolved?

Comment: There's no point of using require in this case. Just do `<img [src]="imagePath" />`

Comment: why u r using `require('./myImage.gif');`

Comment: `<img [src]="imagePath" />`  does not seam to work.

Comment: @Edison, would you suggest a better way to load images dynamically from a property (variable) ?

Comment: @Felix can you tell me what you understood by using `[src]`..?